# jQuery each table count the number of the same string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have this table multiple times, I would like to count the second td `tr:eq(0) td:eq(1)` each table, for example in this case "adam" = 2.

```
   <table>      
        <tr>
            <td>#</td>
            <td>adam</td>
            <td>peter</td>
            <td>danny</td>
            <td>zack</td>
        </tr>
   </table>

   <table>      
        <tr>
            <td>#</td>
            <td>adam</td>
            <td>peter</td>
            <td>danny</td>
            <td>zack</td>
        </tr>
   </table>
```

How would you do that?

Comment: So is it the copy of same table?? I mean values don't change??

Comment: the positions (order) of the names are changing

Comment: I don't understand why users voting down, it's a simple question

Comment: Please show what you have tried. If you haven't tried anything, and want SO to do your work, you need not wonder about downvotings...

Answer (score 3):

Make an object that contains the count of each name:

```
var counts = {};
$('table tr td:nth-child(2)').each(function() {
    var name = $(this).text();
    if (name in counts) {
        counts[name]++;
    } else {
        counts[name] = 1;
    }
}
console.log(counts);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nth-child` selector:

```
$('table tr td:nth-child(2)');
```

### Working Demo

Then use `.each()` to iterate over them individually:

```
$('table tr td:nth-child(2)').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

**Update:** For Finding The length

```
$('table tr td:nth-child(2)').length;
```

Comment: No.. haha, I'm asking how can I count it? if i have 2 adams, I want to count it and get the number

Comment: @user4571629: use `$('table tr td:nth-child(2)').length;`

Answer (score 0):

This will let you count it:

```
var list = '';

$('table:eq(0) td').each(function() {
    list += $(this).text() + ":" + $('td:contains(' + $(this).text() + ')').length + "<br>"
});


$('h3').append(list);
```

results in:

```
#:2
adam:2
peter:2
danny:2
zack:2
```

See this in action below.

```js
var list = '';

$('table:eq(0) td').each(function() {
  list += $(this).text() + ":" + $('td:contains(' + $(this).text() + ')').length + "<br>"
});


$('h3').append(list);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>adam</td>
    <td>peter</td>
    <td>danny</td>
    <td>zack</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>adam</td>
    <td>peter</td>
    <td>danny</td>
    <td>zack</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h3></h3>
```

Comment: Thanks you, this is seem a useful method that I need

Comment: @user4571629 you should look into Barmar's answer.

Comment: @user4571629 i have also updated my answer may be you want to take a look in it.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand it, never mind, thanks anyway